# capistrano unknown database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, capistrano

I tried deploy ror app using capistrano. when i ran the command 'cap deploy:migrations", i got the following errors:
Missing these requried gems:

```
rake aborted!
Unknown database 'hylog_production'
```

do i have to resetup the databases manually on production server?

Answer (score 0):

Have you got your **config/database.yml** file present on the production server and containing the correct database connection details for your production database?

Comment: yes, i figured out that even though capistrano can do the database setup, i still need to create a empty databse first inorder capistrano can do its job. so i created the database using mysql
<pre>
>> mysqladmin -u root -p create hylog_production;
</pre>

then it worked... thanks.